# How can I get mutual relations in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relation like:

```
Keyword - PAID_BY -> App
```

Here, I want to find mutual keywords by apps.

Example:

```
KW1   PAID_BY  App1
KW2   PAID_BY  App1
KW1   PAID_PY  App2
KW1   PAID_PY  App3
KW2   PAID_PY  App3
```

When I try to find mutual keywords for App1 with other apps. I should find a result like:

```
KW1 is mutual keyword between App1 and App2 
and KW1 and KW2 is mutual keyword between App1 and App3
```

Here is my cypher query:

```
MATCH a1:App{id:$idSource} <- PAID_BY - k:Keyword - PAID_BY -> a2:App 
RETURN a1,
       a2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT k) AS mutualKeywordCount,
       COLLECT(DISTINCT k) AS mutualKeywords
```

I tried it but result is not distinct. Is there any suggestion?

It should be for App1 as input:

```
App1  App2 1 KW1
App1  App3 2 KW1,KW2
```

But it looks like:

```
App1  App2 1 KW1
App1  App3 2 KW1,KW2
App1  App3 2 KW1,KW2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISTINCT can also be used in RETURN. Please try this:

```
RETURN DISTINCT a1,
       a2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT k) AS mutualKeywordCount,
       COLLECT(DISTINCT k) AS mutualKeywords
```